# Docker on Heroku exceeded memory quota

Tags: linux, spring-boot, docker, heroku

I try without effect since few to days optimize memory used by my container but during start of my app in Spring Boot an error comes up:

```
2021-11-16T14:39:43.245807+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.152364067.4ead0741-02de-4b30-8781-628c655e5e0d sample#memory_total=840.98MB sample#memory_rss=492.79MB sample#memory_cache=0.03MB sample#memory_swap=348.16MB sample#memory_pgpgin=814490pages sample#memory_pgpgout=863090pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2021-11-16T14:39:43.292468+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=840M(164.2%)
2021-11-16T14:39:43.294393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2021-11-16T14:40:05.323421+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

As we can se memory quota has been exceeded over 64%.

I've no idea what should I do to make my app works correctly on Heroku. Here is my Dockerfile which works:

```
FROM node:14.16.1-alpine3.13

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache bash && \
    apk add --no-cache openjdk8 && \
    apk add --no-cache java-cacerts && \
    update-ca-certificates -f && \
    apk add --no-cache sudo && \
    echo "root:kuba" | chpasswd

USER root

RUN echo "kuba" | sudo -S apk add --no-cache curl && \ 
    mkdir -p /usr/local/lib && \
    cd /usr/local/lib && \
    curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xz && \
    rm heroku/bin/node && \
    ln -s /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku /usr/local/bin/heroku && \
    heroku version

# Setup JAVA_HOME -- useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

# Add an app and listen on port
COPY target/project-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /
COPY project-91878452-firebase-adminsdk-dxv9z-0db48a2d01.json /

EXPOSE 8000
CMD java -jar project-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Tell me if you need something more like my pom.xml or something I don't know what else you need to investigate the issue.

Comment: does this [documentation page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-memory-use) help ?

Comment: Do you need the node JS infra? I would start from a base Java image like FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre